# React Hooks: Can't access updated useState variable outside useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react and creating react app , in this app , food items can be drag to order list using react dnd ,
the problem i am facing is i am not able to get the updated **OrderList** variable in any function outside the useEffect,

in the **addFoodToOrderList** , **useEffect** ,I am printing the same **OrderList** variable but in **addFoodToOrderList** the output is empty , I know useState is async function but while adding 3rd item to order list it should show at least first 2 item but its giving empty array(0) as output , case is different for **useEffect**

code :

```
export default function FoodCardContainer() {
    const [liked,setLiked] = useState("")
    
    function handleLike(e) {
        setLiked(prevNotes => {
            return [...prevNotes,e];
          });
      }
    const [orderList, setOrderList] = useState([]);
      
    const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: "div",
        drop: (item) => {
         addFoodToOrderList(item.id)},
        collect: (monitor) => ({
          isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
        }),
      }));
    
    const addFoodToOrderList = (id) => {
       const orderItem = fooditems.filter((f) => id === f._id)
       setOrderList((preorderLists) => {return [...preorderLists,orderItem[0]]});
       console.log("this one outside useEffect",orderList)
      };
   
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log("this one inside useEffect",orderList)
    },[orderList])
```

my console:

[image]

Comment: I suspect `useDrop` it is memoizing the function it's executing as a closure with the `addFoodToOrderList` and initial `orderList` variable. Whenever the `FoodCard` re-renders, the function passed to `useDrop` may be ignored and continue to be holding on to the first time it was called on initial render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that function passed to `drop` was memoized and never updated.
The [docs](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop) mention this as parameters to the `useDrop`:

> **deps** A dependency array used for memoization. This behaves like the
> built-in useMemoReact hook. The default value is **an empty array for
> function spec**, and an array containing the spec for an object spec.

Since you provided function spec, it defaulted to empty array as deps.

So you should specify deps.

```
const [{
    isOver
}, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: "div",
    drop: (item) => {
        addFoodToOrderList(item.id)
    },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
        isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
    }),
}), [addFoodToOrderList]);
```

Comment: Good find, perhaps include a code snippet showing how to solve it? It's a little weird to me that this hook defaults to an empty array instead of not defining a dependency array and re-capturing the closure on every render. Might be less efficient by default, but would result in less memoization confusion like this question is hitting.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach could be yeah. I added example. They say this "The default value is an empty array for function spec, and an array containing the spec for an object spec."